# Connecting informix through SSIS

Tags: informix, ssis-2012

I need to connect to Informix database.

I have created a DSN (by using 32 bit informix driver) with the details and the test connection is working fine.

When connecting through SSIS, the DSN is not able to connect, the error thrown is:

> sqlhosts file has the database name still error shown it is missing

Comment: Ummmm... I don't recall seeing that error message before.
Anyway, keep in mind that the SSIS agent may run as a different user so maybe the DSN or the environment (INFORMIXDIR/PATH) is not set for all users.  

Try creating a System DSN and make sure the SSIS job is setup to run in x86 mode (Run64BitRuntime=false).
By default it uses x64 which is not going to work if your driver is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact error message?

Which SSIS Version are you using?

Proably the required enviroment variables are not set in the environment of the SSIS process.